# sed single line address seems to go through the whole file

Tags: sed

I have a large file of data. Each line is a single record. Sounds like a job for sed.

I want to inspect a few lines of data, one at a time, but they're json with base64 encoded values. To inspect line 2, I run :

```
sed -n 2p hugeFile | json 'key' | base64 --decode
```

Which works fine, except that sed seems to carry on going through the file.

Am I using sed incorrectly here, or is it really going through every file, checking each lines to see if it's line 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine multiple commands with curly braces, and execute the `q` command to exit immediately.

```
sed -n '2{p;q;}' hugeFile
```

It works like this because you might have multiple commands, or an address that isn't just a single line number. `sed` doesn't optimze the special case where there's just a single command and it's a line number range.

Comment: That helps in this case. But assuming he wants to print a line in the middle of a huge file, how could one prevent [tag:sed] from processing line by line? I assume it's not possible. Could this be addressed with [tag:awk]?

Comment: How would it get to that line in the middle of the file without processing line by line? Text files don't have an index that lets you go straight to a particular line number, you have to read sequentially and count newlines.

Comment: I suddenly realise how little sed I know - I assume that np would tell me what was on line n, rather than n being an address, and p being the print command. I assume then, that `2{p;q;}` says ' on line 2, print the line, then quit'.

Comment: you can also use the -u to pass in stream version (if available in your sed version). On huge file it help by not buffering the file. On huge file i often head/tail the portion of text eventually with a sed on this, it is quicker